# Transparent donation webapp, where anybody can see all donations

Tags: web-apps, online-payment, donation

I am setting up a donation box on a website.

For transparency reasons, I would like all donations too be visible.

- Show total amount since beginning
- Show history of donations (not showing donator's name nor private info)
- As easy to use as Paypal: create an account, like to a bank account, copy-paste some HTML to your website
- SaaS